# Intel Corporation Wireless 7260-AC connection drops and low speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an Intel Corporation Wireless 7260-AC in my notebook running Debian Buster:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

and Kernel:

```
Linux debian 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u2 (2019-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Network-Manager:

```
||/ Name            Version      Architecture Description
+++-===============-============-============-=========================================================
ii  network-manager 1.14.6-2     amd64        network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
```

Network-Manager-Gnome:

```
||/ Name                  Version      Architecture Description
+++-=====================-============-============-=============================================
ii  network-manager-gnome 1.8.20-1.1   amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
```

I have an OpenWrt 18.06.4 running on a TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND v4 with WPA2 Enterprise with a dedicated FreeRadius server. Every thing works as expected except my wifi network connection keeps dropping and mostly I have to restart the network-manager to get it working again, I even have a cronjob running every minute to check the connection and restart the network-manager if needed.
I tried the following without success:

1. disable power saving mode for wifi
2. disable IPV6 with kernel parameter `ipv6.disable=1`
3. Set the Region in /etc/default/crda and in OpenWrt
4. switch the frequency in OpenWrt between a fix channel and auto
5. switch the frequency width between 20MHz and 40MHz
6. I even bought a new wireless card, but the behavior didn't change. The speed is low and the connection keeps dropping

Unfortunately nothing helps. In addition I have a max speed of ~ 17 Mbit/s. Here are some more information:
lspci -vvv

```
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 41
    Region 0: Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee003b8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range B, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 16ms to 55ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP+ BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 90-2e-1c-ff-ff-33-bf-a8
    Capabilities: [14c v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [154 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

iwconfig wlp2s0

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"OpenWrt"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 84:16:F9:E8:A0:56   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:4042   Missed beacon:0
```

nmcli dev wifi

```
IN-USE  SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
*       OpenWrt               Infra  6     405 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X
```

speedtest

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from some.host (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by some.company (City) [3.71 km]: 90.118 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 12.89 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 5.44 Mbit/s
```

here is iftop for running backup job:

```
 Display paused                           1.86Gb                                    3.73Gb                                    5.59Gb                                    7.45Gb                               9.31Gb
└─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────
10.0.10.150                                                                         => 10.0.10.11                                                                          10.8Mb  8.47Mb  8.32Mb
                                                                                    <=                                                                                     184Kb   146Kb   143Kb
```

running iperf on my client connecting to the OpenWrt router:

iperf -c 10.0.10.1:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.10.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.0.10.150 port 46364 connected with 10.0.10.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.8 sec  1.00 MBytes   774 Kbits/sec
```

This shows a very slow connection, I don't know why, because even if the backup job is running now, that didn't affect the `speedtest` command and I have ~ 12 Mbit/s, rather only iperf is very slow. Is there an explanation??

The only thing I could replace now is the rp-sma cables for the wireless card, but I don't know if its worth or I should just replace the notebook. On my work notebook I don't have neither the speed issue nor the connection dropping problem, although I didn't do any thing of the steps above.
I hope some one can give me an advice how this problem occurs and how can I identify the bottleneck. By the way in syslog there is nothing, except the reauthentication with FreeRadius.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could replace the ancient router. That's the first thing that comes to mind here.

Comment: I did. I tested with a TP-Link Archer C7 1750 v5. unfortunately the dynamic vlan assignment for 5GHz with ath10k is not possible and the stability of the 2GHz connection was bad even with other clients, who hadn't a problem with my ancient router. I tested with a netgear WNDR3700 v5 as well and the dynamic vlan assignment worked this time but the connection was dropping every now and then on all clients. So I got my TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND v4 connected again.

Comment: all other clients have no problem with this router. I have a second debian notebook with a wireless speed of ~ 45 Mbit/s and without any connection drops. Windows clients, android devices, iphone and ipads. No problem. That's why I guess it is the rp-sma cables. But I don't know how to find the bottleneck.

Comment: `Bit Rate=48 Mb/s` - unless your wireless access point and wireless card both support MIMO in some way, you should assume your connection to be half-duplex. So the maximum you would expect, in ideal circumstances, is 24Mb/s, and you are getting half - maybe you have something on your notebook causing interference?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue: both my wireless card and and router support MIMO 2x2 with `RX HT20 SGI` and `RX HT40 SGI`. I found indeed a problem with the rp-sma cable for 2.4Ghz, so I replaced the antenna including the cables. Now it works perfect with a speed up to 70 Mbit/s in 2.4Ghz. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the connection drops by replacing the antennas including the rp-sma cables.

The speed fix was:

- revoke all changes made for the wifi connection (power management, 11n disable, software encryption etc)
- download firmware-iwlwifi
- purge the iwlwifi completely and remove all files came with the firmware
- reboot
- reinstall the downloaded firmware-iwlwifi
- rmmod iwlwifi
- modprobe iwlwifi

Now with an Uplink of 200 Mbit/s, I am almost at 70 Mbit/s with the 2.4 GHz, which is fine.